# Can we use async/await in cloud functions in firebase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have to functions called: getMatchDataApi() and saveApiDataToDb(). getMatchDataApi() function returns value from an api and saveApiDataToDb() function is used to store getMatchDataApi() value into firestore database.

```
function getMatchDataApi() {
  var options = {
    method: "GET",
    hostname: "dev132-cricket-live-scores-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
    port: null,
    path: "/scorecards.php?seriesid=2141&matchid=43431",
    headers: {
      "x-rapidapi-host": "dev132-cricket-live-scores-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
      "x-rapidapi-key": "63e55e4f7fmsh8711fb1c0bd9ec2p1d8b4bjsne2b8db0a1a82"
    },
    json: true
  };
  var req = http.request(options, res => {
    var chunks = [];

    res.on("data", chunk => {
      chunks.push(chunk);
    });

    res.on("end", () => {
      var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
      var json = JSON.parse(body);
      playerName = json.fullScorecardAwards.manOfTheMatchName;
      console.log("player name", playerName);
    });
  });
  req.end();
}
```

```
async function saveApiDataToDb() {
  await getMatchDataApi();
  var name = playerName;
  console.log("Aman Singh", name);
}
```

Here i am using async function. So that first i want it should execute this getMatchDataApi() first and returns the value and after that it should print value inside this function saveApiDataToDb().
And then i am calling saveApiDataToDb() as follow:

```
exports.storeMatchData = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
   saveApiDataToDb()
});
```

Comment: I am new to cloud functions in firebase. Please help anyone. Thanks in advance

Comment: `getMatchDataApi` is not returning any promise so you can't await it. Aslo, is `playerName` a global variable?

Comment: Your function should return a promise that resolves when all the async work is complete.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use async/await in cloud functions. But, you can't access/fetch the data outside the google servers in the Spark Plan (Free Plan).
Hope this helps.

Modify your `functions/index.js` file like this way:

```js
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const request = require('request');


    exports.storeMatchData = functions.https.onRequest( async (req, res) => {
        let body = '';
        await getMatchDataApi().then(data => body = data).catch(err => res.status(400).end(err));

        if (!body) {
            return res.status(404).end('Unable to fetch the app data :/');
        }
        // let json = JSON.parse(body);
        // playerName = json.fullScorecardAwards.manOfTheMatchName;
        // console.log("Aman Singh", playerName);
        res.send(body);
    });

    function getMatchDataApi() {
        const options = {
            url: 'https://dev132-cricket-live-scores-v1.p.rapidapi.com/scorecards.php?seriesid=2141&matchid=43431',
            headers: {
                "x-rapidapi-host": "dev132-cricket-live-scores-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
                "x-rapidapi-key": "63e55e4f7fmsh8711fb1c0bd9ec2p1d8b4bjsne2b8db0a1a82"
            },
        };

        return cURL(options);
    }



    function cURL(obj, output = 'body') {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            request(obj, (error, response, body) => {
                if (error)
                    reject(error);
                else if (response.statusCode != 200)
                    reject(`cURL Error: ${response.statusCode} ${response.statusMessage}`);
                else if (response.headers['content-type'].match(/json/i) && output == 'body')
                    resolve(JSON.parse(body));
                else if (output == 'body')
                    resolve(body);
                else
                    resolve(response);
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: i am having blaze plan. So how i can use async/await in my code which i am mentioned above.

Comment: so what i want to do is: 1. getMatchDataApi() this function should run first and return the "playerName" value 2.saveApiDataToDb() then this function should execute to store "playerName" value into my db. So i have to use async/await functions. So i am confussed to how to use it?

Comment: You have to use promises in this case, inside the `getMatchDataApi()` function. 
Better to go with [https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise)  or [https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

Comment: Bonus: **Official** [firebase/functions-samples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/remote-config-diff/functions/index.js)

Comment: i go through these function-samples and the link what you have given. Can you help me out by writing the code how to use promise or async/await in above code. It will really help. Thank you

Comment: Here it is what you want - [https://gist.github.com/webcdn/b931e8831af0540e7cc52d7b0809ea38](https://gist.github.com/webcdn/b931e8831af0540e7cc52d7b0809ea38)

Comment: Thanks for help.

Comment: Thanks for the help dear @MohitG. I wasn't aware of the limitation regarding async calls in the spark plan.

Answer (score 0):

I try to solve my issue using promise in cloud functions. so it could help someone.
This is my cloud function

```
exports.storeMatchData = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  a().then(
    result => {
      saveApiDataToDb(result);
    },
    error => {}
  );
});
```

This is the function from which i am calling api and resolving its data first what i want

```
var options = {
  method: "GET",
  hostname: "dev132-cricket-live-scores-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
  port: null,
  path: "/scorecards.php?seriesid=2141&matchid=43431",
  headers: {
    "x-rapidapi-host": "dev132-cricket-live-scores-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key": "63e55e4f7fmsh8711fb1c0bd9ec2p1d8b4bjsne2b8db0a1a82"
  },
  json: true
};

var options1 = {
  method: "GET",
  hostname: "dev132-cricket-live-scores-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
  port: null,
  path: "/matches.php?completedlimit=5&inprogresslimit=5&upcomingLimit=5",
  headers: {
    "x-rapidapi-host": "dev132-cricket-live-scores-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key": "63e55e4f7fmsh8711fb1c0bd9ec2p1d8b4bjsne2b8db0a1a82"
  }
};

var a = function getMatchDataApi() {
  // Return new promise
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Do async job

    let firstTask = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var req = http.request(options, res => {
        var chunks = [];
        var arr = [];

        res.on("data", chunk => {
          chunks.push(chunk);
        });

        res.on("end", () => {
          var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
          var json = JSON.parse(body);
          const playerName = json.fullScorecardAwards.manOfTheMatchName;
          resolve(playerName);
        });
      });
      req.end();
    });

    let secondTask = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var req = http.request(options1, res => {
        var chunks = [];
        var arr = [];

        res.on("data", chunk => {
          chunks.push(chunk);
        });

        res.on("end", () => {
          var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
          var json = JSON.parse(body);
          const playerName = json;
          resolve(playerName);
        });
      });
      req.end();
    });

    Promise.all([firstTask, secondTask]).then(
      result => {
        resolve(result);
      },
      error => {
        reject(error);
      }
    );
  });

};
```

This is the function in which I am going to use getMatchDataApi() values after resolving in this function.

```
function saveApiDataToDb(data) {
  console.log("Name of player", data[0]);
}
```